# Trying to get chunk of python code to run a certain number of times

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have a rock paper scissors game programmed and I have some win counters with it. I would like the game to repeat until one of the win counters has hit 4 but can't figure out a good way to do it.

I tried using a while loop but couldn't get it to stop repeating over and over and couldn't find a way to stop it.

```py
import random
import time

moves=["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

play_move=str(input("Please choose rock, paper, or scissors: "))

computer_move= moves[random.randint(0,2)]

print("Ready \n")
time.sleep(1)
print("Set \n")
time.sleep(1)
print("GO! \n")
time.sleep(1)

comp_wins=0

player_wins=0

ties= 0

if player_wins <= 4 or comp_wins <=4:
    if play_move == computer_move:
        print("Both players chose", play_move, "and there is a tie, please play again")
        ties= ties+1
    elif play_move == "rock":
        if computer_move == "paper":
            print(computer_move, "beats", play_move, "You have lost!")
            comp_wins= comp_wins+1
        else:
            print(play_move, "beats", computer_move, "You have won!")
            player_wins=player_wins+1
    elif play_move == "paper":
        if computer_move == "scissors":
            print(computer_move, "beats", play_move, "You have lost!")
            comp_wins= comp_wins+1
        else:
            print(play_move, "beats", computer_move, "You have won!")
            player_wins=player_wins+1
    elif play_move == "scissors":
        if computer_move == "rock":
            print(computer_move, "beats", play_move, "You have lost!")
            comp_wins= comp_wins+1
        else:
            print(play_move, "beats", computer_move, "You have won!")
            player_wins=player_wins+1
    else:
        print("Your selection was invalid please try again")
```

Comment: You haven't shown your failed attempt at a [`while` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while). Something like `while (player_wins < 4) and (comp_wins < 4): ... ` should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
import time

moves=["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

# Initially setting the score to 0
comp_wins = player_wins = 0

# while none of them reaches a score of 4 this loop will continue
# if either of them gets a score of 4 we terminate the loop
while comp_wins<4 and player_wins<4:
    play_move = str(input("Please choose rock, paper, or scissors: "))
    computer_move= moves[random.randint(0, 2)]
    print("Ready...")
    # time.sleep(1)
    print("Set...")
    # time.sleep(1)
    print("GO!")
    # time.sleep(1)

    ties= 0

    if play_move == computer_move:
        print("Both players chose", play_move, "and there is a tie, please play again")
        ties = ties+1
    elif play_move == "rock":
        if computer_move == "paper":
            print(computer_move, "beats", play_move, "You have lost!")
            comp_wins = comp_wins+1
        else:
            print(play_move, "beats", computer_move, "You have won!")
            player_wins = player_wins+1
    elif play_move == "paper":
        if computer_move == "scissors":
            print(computer_move, "beats", play_move, "You have lost!")
            comp_wins = comp_wins+1
        else:
            print(play_move, "beats", computer_move, "You have won!")
            player_wins = player_wins+1
    elif play_move == "scissors":
        if computer_move == "rock":
            print(computer_move, "beats", play_move, "You have lost!")
            comp_wins = comp_wins+1
        else:
            print(play_move, "beats", computer_move, "You have won!")
            player_wins=player_wins+1
    else:
        print("Your selection was invalid please try again")
```

I added a while loop with comments. At first, we declared

```
comp_wins = player_wins = 0
```

So that we can access them in while loop.

```
while comp_wins<4 and player_wins<4:
```

Now in while loop, we are checking if both of their scores are below 4. As soon as any of them reaches the score of 4 we terminate.

Comment: You need to use an `or` in the loop, not an `and`. Also the first `if` condition is now redundant with the loop's condition. I'll edit for you.

Comment: Hi Guimoute, 
I haven't changed any of his code, I just added a condition with while loop. 

And for the while loop, I am checking if both the scores are below 4. I case any of them reaches 4 the loop is broken. 

And I saw the rest of your suggested edits. They are fine but I can't edit it as I do not have enough scores to do suggested edits.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad it's indeed an `and`!